# php DOMDocument: return nodeValue including childNode

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

**file.html**

```
<div>
    <a href="">apple</a>
</div>
```

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$html->loadHTML( file_get_contents('file.html') );
$nodes =  $html->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($nodes as $i=>$node) {
     if($node->nodeName == 'div')
     echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

this returns 'apple'. How do I get the child node including the child node's value, as in:
   `<a href="#">apple</a>`

Comment: What you want is the 'innerHTML' of the node, which PHP DOM doesn't support.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89802 details how to fake it.

Comment: @Marc B: Nice! Though I wish I didn't have to "fake" it

Comment: @Marc B: You should answer with that so I can upvote you.

Comment: @MarcB There is a way, it's just not as obvious. See the answer I just posted.

Comment: Thanks, but onteria's answer looks to be a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the a dom node to [DOMDocument::saveXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) and it will spit out the actual HTML instead:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$html->loadHTML( file_get_contents('file.html') );
$nodes =  $html->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($nodes as $i=>$node) {
     if($node->nodeName == 'div') {
       //Navigate to the specific element you want
       //then pass it to saveXML
       echo $html->saveXML($node->childNodes->item(1));
     }
}
```